# problems with the collatz sequence Input validation practice project

Tags: python

[image: collatz sequence Input validation]

Im fairly new to coding, and Im practicing along the Automate the boring stuff with python book when I came across the collatz sequence problem.

As you guys can see from my code, in the 1st time, I typed "puppy" and it said "NameError" and ended the run altogether without returning to the input phase. In the 2nd time, I typed "89", and then "puppy", and it printed out the valueerror text along with the result from last time.

How can I fix this for both the times? Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you seen the [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) keyword?

Comment: Please do not post code as images, Stackoverflow engine can beautifully format your code when included as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the value of 268 came from the last calculation and wasn't overwritten due to the exception caught with "puppy". To fix that, simply use the `continue` keyword to loop back to the "try" condition:

```
except ValueError :
    print('You must enter an integer')
    continue
```